# navigator.camera.getPicture not working in android

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app using Cordova and Worklight 6.3 and I have a problem using the camera.getPicture function.

Please check below code snippet for camera.

```
var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    targetWidth: 720,
    targetHeight: 600,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    correctOrientation: true,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
};
```

Android Error logs:

```
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168): Uncaught exception from plugin
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:560)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:534)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:376)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.takePicture(CameraLauncher.java:302)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.callTakePicture(CameraLauncher.java:276)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.execute(CameraLauncher.java:185)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:86)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:153)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:61)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:40)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-04 12:43:26.727: E/PluginManager(1168):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I follow ibm Fix but the same error
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_android_cam_api_24.html

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
```

Comment: Is the issue specific to a version of Android?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Vinin K, I test with several versions the same problem :/

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml, this line seems to be incorrectly quoted - 
<b>android:authorities="${applicationId.fileprovider"</b>. Could you please change it to <b>android:authorities="${applicationId.fileprovider}"</b> and try and update to us?

Answer (score -2):

add the below line in default.xml

```
<preference name="applicationId" value="com.APPlol.test" /> 
// ID in widget is the value
<widget id="com.APPlol.test"></widget> // in config .xml
```